# Why isn't Props passing down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a feeling it's a timing thing, but not sure how to fix it. In the code below, I'm using an API to `setState` on my `contacts` array, which does work. When I log it, it looks exactly as expected  However, when I pass it down to my child component, and simply try to log it, I get an empty array.

**Parent Component**

```
    class Database extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                clients: [],
                contacts: []
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            fetch(API_URL + '/clients/all')
                .then(res => {
                    if (!res.ok) {
                        throw new Error();
                    }
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        clients: result.sort((a, b) => a.client.localeCompare(b.client)),
                    });
                    // console.log(result);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(
                    fetch(API_URL + `/contacts/all`)
                        .then(res => {
                            if (!res.ok) {
                                throw new Error();
                            }
                            return res.json();
                        })
                        .then((result) => {
                            this.setState({ contacts: result });
                            console.log(result);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        })
                );
        }



        render() {
            return (
                <Div>
                    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                        <Container className="database">
                            {this.state.clients.map(client => (
                                <ClientAccordion
                                    key={client.id}
                                    short={client.short}
                                    client={client.client}
                                    address={client.address}
                                    address2={client.address2}
                                    city={client.city}
                                    state={client.state}
                                    zip={client.zip}
                                    lead={client.lead}
                                    logo={client.logo}
                                    color1={client.color1}
                                    color2={client.color2}
                                    contacts={this.state.contacts}
                                    // {...this.state}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </Container>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </Div>

            )
        }
    }

    export default Database;
```

**Child Component** - in the child component, everything passes down fine, except the contacts.  Even just trying to log them in the `componentDidMount` function just logs an empty array. I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm stuck and would appreciate any help. I just need the `contacts` array from the parent to pass down so that I can then filter it in my child component.

```
class ClientAccordion extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            color1: "#000",
            color2: "#fff",
            filteredContacts: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            color1: this.props.color1,
            color2: this.props.color2,
        }, this.filterContacts);
    }

    filterContacts() {
        console.log(`Unfiltered Contacts: ${this.props.contacts}`);
        this.setState({
            filteredContacts: this.props.contacts.filter(contact => contact.short === this.props.short)
        }, console.log(this.state.filteredContacts));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <StyledAccordion>
                    <StyledCard>
                        <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={this.props.short}>
                            <Row>
                                <Col xs={4}><div>{this.props.client}</div></Col>
                                <Col><div>{this.props.short}</div></Col>
                                <Col><div>{this.props.city}</div></Col>
                            </Row>
                            
                        </Accordion.Toggle>
                        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={this.props.short}>
                            <StyledCard.Body>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col xs={7}>
                                        <div>{this.props.address} </div>
                                        <div>{this.props.address2}</div>
                                        <div>{this.props.city}, {this.props.state} {this.props.state}</div>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                                <hr />
                                <h5>Contacts</h5>
                                <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Birthday</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {this.state.filteredContacts.map(contact => (
                                    <tr key={contact.id}>
                                        <td>{contact.jobtitle}</td>
                                        <td>{contact.firstname}</td>
                                        <td>{contact.lastname}</td>
                                        <td><a href={`mailto:${contact.email}`}>{contact.email}</a></td>
                                        <td>{contact.birthday}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>
                            </StyledCard.Body>
                        </Accordion.Collapse>
                    </StyledCard>
                </StyledAccordion>
            </ThemeProvider>
        )
    }



}

export default ClientAccordion;
```

Comment: `.then(fetch(API_URL + `/contacts/all`)` this is always calling `fetch`, regardless of the promise. You'd probably want something like: `.then(() => fetch(API_URL + `/contacts/all`)`

Comment: Hi Adam. Could you simply and reduce the test code for minimum reproducibility?

Comment: You should use getDerivedStateFromProps hook in child component instead of setting parents props as child's state vars.

Comment: in your child component you call filterContacts() in didMount, I guess that in did mount moment contacts does not exist yet. Try to repeat all your action in didUpdate too